# i am beginner in PHP and unable to set path

Tags: php, codeigniter

please help me to use path with php tag with folder name self define.

```
<?php
  /* Uploadify */

  // Define a destination
  $targetFolder = <?php echo base_url();?>'uploads'; // here is the problem

  if (file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder . '/' . $_POST['filename'])) 
    {
      echo 1;
    } 
  else 
    {
      echo 0;
  }
?>
```

Comment: You're trying to open PHP tags inside PHP... 
`$targetFolder = base_url().'uploads';`

Comment: Have you echoed $targetFolder to see what it holds?

Comment: @AndyHolmes This is a Syntax error, it won't show anything he echos.

Comment: use file helper from codeigniter, you should read the documentation, all you need there is in doc

Comment: @Pinki literally just noticed that after you and i commented :P

Comment: if the answer has been given, please provide it in the answer area below

Comment: Careful when mixing data from `$_POST` with file paths, any data coming from a remote user is potentially dangerous and must always be validated with proper filtering before being used. This code in particular seems innocent enough, but even so it allows a hacker to detemine what files exist in your server -- anywhere -- not only in your website's folder, by using relative paths. Depending on the case a similar code can be used to read any file including the source codes of your PHP files that may include sensitive information such as database and SMTP server passwords.

Comment: @havenard thanks for your advise. i will follow.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like someone gave this answer in the comments section - adding the full updated code here in the answer for clarity:

```
<?php
  /* Uploadify */

  // Define a destination
  $targetFolder = base_url() . 'uploads'; // notice no nested PHP tags

  if (file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder . '/' . $_POST['filename'])) 
  {
      echo 1;
  } 
  else 
  {
      echo 0;
  }
```